# Entity Framework 6 - GetExecutionPlan performance hit

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, query-optimization

I am executing a single very complex query using Entity Framework 6, the whole query is built on the standard `IQueryable<>` interface provided by `DbContext`.

Even though the generated query is very complex, it executes in several miliseconds on my database server. All the performed joins are reasonable, it seems that it all uses the right indexes.

But when I profile the application using *dotTrace*, I see that around 1-2 seconds are spent just when Entity Framework is preparing the execution plan (`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan`).

[image: performance snapshot]

It seems that in this case, the Entity Framework is generating too much overhead. It's not even that the resulting query would be bad and would perform bad on the database server. Its the query generation itself, which is taking too much time. I never before experienced this type of problem when using any ORM.

My question is: Are there some possibilities of optimizing this? Are there some options that I can try before I abandon EF for this use-case?

Comment: Are you using GroupJoins?

Comment: Hi Tom, did you managed to fix that?

Comment: @kemsky I rewrote this part in SQL as performance was important there for us.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (if you can) is to make that a stored procedure (perhaps with input parameters that you pass at execution time).  The execution plan for stored procedures is generated and retained at the time they are saved; and can also automatically re-generate if schema changes occur.

It is not realistic in this case to expect to generate such a complex execution plan at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jeff. This certainly is one of my options. However, this would basically mean abandoning LINQ and using Entity Framework just to parse the results. I have many parts of this query added dynamically (dynamic filtering, grouping and sorting), so at first I'd like to see if there are any options of optimizing the existing solution rather than rewriting it all in T-SQL.